# LibGDX Game Gives a Blank Screen After Some Time

Tags: android, libgdx

I've created a game using LibGDX, and everything works fine on my phone, a Samsung S3, but a friend of mine reports that on his Sony Xperia T the screen goes blank after playing the game for about 3 minutes or so. This is reproducible and happens every time.

I was playing with my code and realised that I could force a blank screen by disposing of assets and then trying to use them. I also realised that my code is a bit crap because:

- I instantiate one Screen instance and reuse it many times
- In my show() method of each screen I create an instance of a Skin and assign it to a private instance field.

Which make me think that every time a Screen is shown with show(), a new Skin instance is created and any reference to a previous Skin instance that was created during a previous call to show() will be lost and available for garbage collection.

The [LibGDX documentation](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TheArchitecture) states that graphical assets are not available to the garbage collector, and in any case the garbage collector would only see a small reference to a class, not the actual graphical asset, which is why you have to call dispose() on them yourself to save memory.

My question is: if the garbage collector runs and cleans up my old Skin reference, will that automatically dispose() the graphical assets to which it was attached, so that when I try and create a new Skin referencing those assets, they have already been disposed?

If so, is there a way to test for this?

I'm thinking the Xperia T my friend has is being more aggressive with garbage collection than my S3.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For any Object that implements the Disposable interface in LibGDX, you must call `dispose()` on it yourself before it goes out of scope and gets GC'ed. That's because all of these classes have stuff in native or GPU memory that the GC doesn't know about.

It's up to you how you want to organize your code, but I would say that any class that you use to instantiate stuff should also clean up after itself by calling `dispose()` on all its Disposables before you stop referencing it.

So you probably have a custom class that implements Screen. I would give your Screen-implementing class it's own `dispose()` method that calls `dispose()` on any Disposable that it instantiated. Then remember to call `dispose()` on your screen before it goes out of scope.

Using a static variable to reference your Skin theoretically should be OK as long as you clean up your old Skin before replacing the reference. But it doesn't seem like this would be very robust against bugs.

I can't tell exactly why your screen is going black without seeing a lot more code. One test you could do is use a clear color other than black, so you will see silhouettes of your meshes if it's only a texture loading problem.

Comment: Is there any way to test that I have correctly disposed everything?

Comment: See http://bitiotic.com/blog/2013/05/23/libgdx-and-android-application-lifecycle/ for some tips on testing the different lifecycle interactions between Libgdx and Android.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are creating something in 'create' method, you should dispose it in 'dispose' method of screen.
- If you are creating something in 'resume' method, you should dispose it in 'pause' method of the screen.
- Similarly, if you are creating it in 'show' or 'resize' method, you should dispose it in 'hide' method.

Hope this helps.